# How to use mechanize to handle with an auto page-turn after login?

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I met some questions when I use mechanize to login a website.Here is my code.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get("https://example.com/login")
login_form = page.forms.first
login_form.username = 'username'
login_form.password = 'password'
page = agent.submit(login_form)
pp page
```

But I found that there is a turn page after I login and it lasts about 3 secs when I use my browser.
So the it returns such a page.

```
#<Mechanize::Page
 {url #<URI::HTTPS:0xb6c5e764 URL:https://example.com/takelogin.php>}
 {meta_refresh #<Mechanize::Page::MetaRefresh "" "index.php">}
 {title nil}
 {iframes}
 {frames}
 {links}
 {forms}>
```

I'm wondering what I can do with it

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to set Mechanize to follow the meta refresh:

```
agent.follow_meta_refresh = true
```